# Homepage shows as not secure until I reload it

Tags: browser, http

When I start my browser (e.g. Chrome) and enter something in the address bar (not a URL but a word for example) then it redirects me to the Google search for this word. In these cases there is not the usual lock that says the connection is secure but it says that the connection is not secure. If I reload the page, the lock is there and the page shows as secure. This does not always happen when I start the browser but most of the times.

What's the reason for this behaviour?

I use Windows 10 Version 21H1, and the Google Chrome browser. Also I update my system whenever the system asks me to do so.

I just installed the update to Windows 10 Version 21H2 and the behaviour did not occur since then, but because the behaviour does not occur always, I don't know whether it has something to do with this update.

For some reason I cannot comment the question after it has been migrated here, therefore I edit the question: @LPChip Thanks for the suggestion, while I could not reproduce the error since the Windows update, I checked the URL of the default search engine of the Chrome browser, however for the Google site there is no normal URL but something like {Google:baseURL}search?q=... and "google.com" as a the abbreviated name. How can I find out if this refers to http or https? And why would it be http as default? I did not change this setting and I think the Chrome default should be https?

**Update:** I just could reproduce the problem again. The URL is an https address ("https://www.google.com/search?q="...), so that does not seem to be the problem.

**Update 2:** Thanks for the suggestions in the comments! I uninstalled Chrome, deleted the Chrome directory in the Appdata/Local/Google directory, rebooted the PC and installed Chrome again. This did not solve the problem. Next I set the default search URL to "https://www.google.com/search?q=%s", this solved the problem. While the behaviour does not occur anymore, I am wondering: **Am I fine now, or is this just a symptom of something malicious on my PC that I have to take care of?** My antivirus did not detect anything suspicious. What I also found interesting: The behaviour depended on the search term, e.g. if I searched for "yahoo", the behaviour occured, but if I searched for "test" it did not occur. Does this support the hypothesis that it is a mixed content warning?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133640/discussion-on-question-by-simplemind-homepage-shows-as-not-secure-until-i-reload).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Potential Solutions

- **Define an explicit secure Default Search Engine** within the Chrome settings area, and then set it to be the default. Restart Chrome and then try again and see if it still occurs.

  - https://encrypted.google.com
- **Uninstall Chrome**, reboot, and then reinstall Chrome. Something in the Chrome `/appdata` directory may have become corrupt which a reinstall and reboot may resolve.
- If you machine is getting Chrome group policies applied either locally or in a domain which the computer is joined then enforced policies could cause this so talk with your IT adminstrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not sure which answer should get the bounty because all three answers have been helpful / educational for me and I went with Michalng's answer, I hope that is ok. Your answer is very helpful and will benefit other people having the same issue.

Comment: Giving this an up as well as it is nicely solution oriented compared to mine. Defining `https://www.google.com` as explicit search engine is what solved it for OP initially, possibly the fresh Chrome install does the same for `{google:baseURL}`. Generally helpful for others who may land here.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: Since me and OP now cannot replicate the "Not secure" warning anymore, this answer provides two theories, not a definite answer. For general testing, it is important to clear browser data (cookies, cache and HSTS `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` data) for Google domains.*

#### Theory 1: HSTS

The default search engine in Chrome is defined via `{google:baseURL}` prefix, which may be `http://google.com` or `http://www.google.com`, hence a plain HTTP URL.

On my tests, `http://google.com` redirects to `http://www.google.com` first, which redirects to `https://www.google.com`, which is HTTPS secured and sets an [HSTS header](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header. This however may depend on the actual Google server/data center used, based on geographical location and also time as of current data center load. Also the client affects this, e.g. with `curl`, `http://www.google.com` neither redirects to HTTPS nor does `https://www.google.com` respond with an HSTS header.

On first access with Chrome, during redirects, a plain HTTP URL is hence accessed intermediately, which may cause the warning, even that the final URL is HTTPS.

On page reload, when not clearing at least HSTS data (`chrome://net-internals/#hsts`), Chrome does not really access `http://www.google.com` but developer tools show `Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect; Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS` on that URL, indicating that it internally switches to the HTTPS URL directly as expected, so that the plain HTTP URL and hence the warning is bypassed.

#### Theory 2: Mixed content

On first access, depending on the search term, an external plain HTTP resource may be loaded, known as [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) when the parent website is served via HTTPS. This expectedly throws a "Not secure" warning.

On page reload, when the browser cache for this external resource is not cleared, the same resource is stored in browser cache already, hence not pulled from the external plain HTTP URL anymore and the warning bypassed.

The Yahoo logo when using `yahoo` as search term is however no external resource, but provided as base64 encoded data directly from the Google page. The `data:image/png;base64,` prefix indicates this, the following characters or the URL contains the encoded image itself. Opening such URL directly via address bar shows a "Not secure" icon, as it is indeed not an HTTPS authorized source, but when given as resource from an HTTPS website, it does not show a warning. While we wouldn't expect this from the Google website, it may be possible that mixed content is served, depending on the search term, on uncached access.

Comment: upvote so you get a chance at half the bounty

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue by searching for "yahoo": note the little (i) badge at the left of the address bar.
[image]

A problem here could be that the "Yahoo" logo which the search pulls in through the informative box, is classified as a "non secure" item (although in reality it's an inline image). If I load only the image, I get a "not secure" icon on the left of the address bar.
[image]

So, yes, what you got could be a **mixed content warning**. - ***but see my edit at the end***.

In any case, it is not in any way dangerous. There's nothing wrong with your PC. You could get the same issue depending on the search terms you insert, if in the google-produced information box for some reason there's an image served over a non-secure connection.

---

**Further information:**

As you can read on [googles support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?visit_id=637790543188356386-977389655), according to the connection, the browser will switch according to content:
[image]

Only the bottom "Not secure or dangerous" really can become any threat, as on the image below:
[image]

---

### EDIT - Possible explanation

I could not reproduce the issue on a second attempt. However, what I note is: if you type any search term into the address bar and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, for a split-second you will see the `info or not secure` icon. You can see the same behaviour if you enter the URL of any website which you haven't visited before, without èxplicitly specifying the `https` protocol: during page load, you'll see the `info or not secure` icon, before it reverts to the `Secure` icon once you have been redirected to a `https` connection, and the browser has been able to check the security certificates of all the content.

This makes me suppose that in the following case can happen such behaviour:

- google has renewed its security certificate since you last used the browser, the old certificate is not valid anymore
- EITHER at the same time, you have just started up the browser and it is busy doing some background task
- OR some packet gets lost due to a very short network interruption, and certificate validity could not be checked.
- --> with the consequence that the browser was not able to fully verify the validity of the secure connection for all elements on the page: it will "get stuck" at the `info or not secure` icon.

Once you reload the page, the security certificate will be checked and you'll get the `secure`icon.

So, in any case, there's nothing wrong with your PC. And there's nothing dangerous going on.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! :) Do you know why the behaviour did not occur anymore after I manually changed the default search engine URL? And why reloading the page also made the site display as secure?

Comment: This answer is at least partly incorrect since the Yahoo logo is not loaded from anywhere but provided as base64 encoded data directly with the Google page. You can check via developer tools > network tab > force-reload browser to clear cache (CTRL+F5) and check whether you see any "http" in the scheme column, which is not the case. I cannot see any mixed content on my tests, actually cannot replicate the issue at all with any search term, but HSTS may be related.

Comment: @simplemind see my edit

Comment: @MichaIng You're right, I've edited accordingly. And see my possible explanation at the end

Comment: This points into direction of HSTS, see my answer.

Comment: @simpleminds if you dont find a correct answer, consider awarding the bounty to Michalng - he has done some work and can use the rep. If you don't award the bounty points will be lost

Comment: @1NN I gave the bounty to Michalng's answer. Thanks for your answer, too!